# Do not stop and stop not

Tags: syntax

What is the difference between these two versions?

> Arise, awake, and stop not until the goal is reached.

> Arise, awake, and do not stop until the goal is reached.

Which one is better?

Comment: The difference is that '[verb] not' is an obsolete grammatical construction. You should always use 'Do not [verb]'. _Stop not_ sounds as though you were humorously imitating the language of several centuries ago.

Answer (score 0):

The construction in the first example *stop not* would be understood but sounds unusual. However as a rhetorical device it might be possible as in Kennedy's inaugural speech

> And so, my fellow Americans: ask not what your country can do for you — ask what you can do for your country.
> My fellow citizens of the world: ask not what America will do for you, but what together we can do for the freedom of man.

Taken from https://www.ushistory.org/documents/ask-not.htm

But really you should avoid the construction.